# How to add a "Run lua script" option in the context menu

Tags: windows, lua

I'm trying to add an option to run a lua script by right-clicking on the file.

I've already managed to add a "run as lua" option in the context menu and make it run a .bat file.

The program needs to execute

`lua (file path)`

But I don't know how to get this information into the command line.

Comment: Can you please clarify whether you want the context menu entry to run lua with selected file path as an argument, or to run a batch file?

Comment: Basicly, I want to run the command `lua (file path)` whenever I click on "Run as lua" after right-clicking a .lua file.

The only way I found to run a command by clicking on a context menu option was to run a .bat file that contains the command.

I'm just trying to figure out what argument I should use in that .bat file to refer to the file path of the lua script that I'm trying to execute.

Comment: But overall, I'm just trying to execute the `lua (file path)` command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found how to do it!

Forget about running a batch file to run the program, just set `cmd /k lua %1` as the value of the context menu entry.

If you want to add a "run as lua" option to the context menu of a .lua file, just create an empty text document and paste that in it:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.lua]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.lua\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.lua\shell\Run as lua]
@="&Run as lua"
"icon"="C:\\Windows\\system32\\imageres.dll,236"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.lua\shell\Run as lua\command]
@="cmd /k lua "%1""
```

Then change the extension from .txt to .reg and double click on the file. The option will be added to your context menu.

If you wish to remove it, just do Win+R and type regedit then navigate to HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.lua and remove the shell key (or folder if you prefer)